# Issues integrating response from OpenWeatherMap in to my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the OpenWeatherMap API to get to display certain items in HTML and my code does not display them.

```js
$('.`btn`').click(function() {
  var city = $('.inputValue').val();
  var key = '88da1611665dfe9338cd6679dee95466';

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      q: city,
      appid: key,
      units: 'metric'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var temp = '';
      $.each(data.weather, function(index, val) {
        wf += '<p><b>' + data.name + "</b><img src=" + val.icon + ".png></p>" +
         data.main.temp + '&deg;F ' + ' | ' + val.main + ", " +
          val.humidity + val.wind + val.uv
      }, $("showWeather").html(temp));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="4">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <p><b>Search for a city:</p></b>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input type="search" class="inputValue" placeholder="" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success">
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 id="showWeather" class="date"></h2>
      <p>Temperature:</p>
      <p>Humidity:</p>
      <p>Wind Speed:</p>
      <p>UV Index:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few individual issues in your code:

- You have backticks in the `.btn` selector which are invalid, remove them.
- You need to prevent the standard form submission so that the AJAX call can fire and return data without the page refreshing. To do this call `preventDefault()` on the event which is fired, ideally on the `submit` of the `form`, not `click` of `.btn`.
- `</p></b>` tags are the wrong way around
- `.html(temp)` needs to be placed outside the `each()`, and definitely not as an additional argument passed to it
- `wf +=` should be `temp +=` as that's what your variable is called
- You can use `map()` along with template literals to build the HTML string more succinctly.
- You're missing the `#` on `$('showWeather')`
- `wind` is an object so you can't concatenate it to the string directly. Access its `speed` or `deg` properties (or both).
- `humidity` is a property of `main`, not the `weather` you're looping through
- There is no `uv` property anywhere in the response, so that needs to be removed.

With all that fixed, try this:

```js
$('.d-flex').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var city = $('.inputValue').val();
  var key = '88da1611665dfe9338cd6679dee95466';

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      q: city,
      appid: key,
      units: 'metric'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      let html = data.weather.map(loc => `<p><b>${data.name}</b><img src="${loc.icon}.png" /></p>${data.main.temp}&deg;F | ${loc.main}, ${data.main.humidity}%, ${data.wind.speed}kph @ ${data.wind.deg}&deg;`);
      $("#showWeather").html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="4">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <p><b>Search for a city:</b></p>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input type="search" class="inputValue" placeholder="" aria-label="Search" value="miami">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success">
            Search
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 id="showWeather" class="date"></h2>
      <p>Temperature:</p>
      <p>Humidity:</p>
      <p>Wind Speed:</p>
      <p>UV Index:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this, i noticed when i run the code the date disappears , there is a class date in the h2, wondering how to get that to display in there, this is what I have in JS var currentDay = document.querySelector('.date');
currentDay.textContent = dayjs().format('MM/D/YYYY');

Comment: That's a separate issue with the dayjs library you're using. I'd suggest starting a new question for it.

Comment: hi @Rory McCrossan , when i run this code everything works perfectly except the image icon does not load, was wondering why, any ideas?

Comment: That depends on how you're building the icon `img` in your HTML. The URL should take the value of `weather.icon` and append it to the URL, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386144/519413