# I can't show the meteorological icon

Tags: javascript, html, openweathermap

I am creating a time application using the Openweather API. I try to show the meteorological icon corresponding to the selected city and the meteorological state.

My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
                <div class="media-content">
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            <strong>
                                    <h1 class="has-text-inf o"> {{ ciutatActual.weather[0].icon }} </h1>
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

javascript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#eltemps',
data: {
    selectedCity: "",
    ciutatActual: null,
    ciutats: [
            "Barcelona",
            "Lleida",
            "Zaragoza",
            "Sevilla",
            "Madrid",
            "Paris",
            "Melbourne",
            "Moscow",
            "Pekin",
            "Marrakech"]
},
created: function () {
    this.selectedCity = this.ciutats[0]
},
watch: {
    selectedCity: function (){
        this.getWeather(this.selectedCity)
    }
},
methods: {
    getWeather(city) {
        const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&units=metric&lang=ca&appid=8660dddfbe5f16ee37dbd6883d8f07d5';
        fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(function (item) {
                vm.ciutatActual = item;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
    itemClicked: function(item) {
        this.getWeather();
        this.onClick(item);
    }
}
```

})

The ruling comes from here: {{ciutatactual.weather [0] .icon}}

that instead of showing the icon it shows me just one code

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177417/how-to-display-openweathermap-weather-icon#answer-44234308

Comment: I try it but is not works for me