# How to access Weather API icon id?

Tags: reactjs, nested

Same situation as in this [How to display openweathermap weather icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177417/how-to-display-openweathermap-weather-icon)

Why I cannot get an id for icon, with this code ?

```
const value = weather.weather
        console.log('icon', value)
        console.log('icon', value[0].icon)
        const url = `http://openweathermap.org/img/${value[0].icon}.png`
        return(
            <div>
                <div> temperature {weather?.main?.temp} Celcius</div>
                <img src='url' alt="icon" width="120" height="100"></img>
                <p>wind {weather?.wind?.speed} m/s</p>
            </div>
            
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it:

```
const url = `http://openweathermap.org/img/${value?.[0].icon}.png`
```