# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')

Tags: javascript, icons, openweathermap

I am creating a weather app as my first project and so far through research, the community(namely this site), and just trying things out when I get stuck I've been able to resolve most of my issues. However, I'm having trouble dynamically getting the weather icon from the open weather map API.

My JavaScript thus far:

```
weatherData = {
    getWeatherInfo: function (city) {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apiTag}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => this.unveilWeather(data));
    },
    unveilWeather: function (data) {
    const {name} = data;
    const {icon} = data.weather[0];
    const {description} = data.weather[0];
    const {temp} = data.main;
    const {humidity} = data.main;
    const {speed} = data.wind;
    console.log(name, icon, description, temp, humidity, speed);
    document.querySelector("#City").innerText = "Weather in " + name; 
    document.querySelector("#weatherIcon").setAttribute ("src,"`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`); 
    document.querySelector("#cityWeatherDescription").innerText = description;
    document.querySelector(".temperature").innerText = Math.round(temp) + " °F";
    document.querySelector (".humidity-weather-stat").innerText = "Humidity :" +  humidity + "%";
    document.querySelector(".wind-speed-weather-stat").innerText = "Wind Speed :" + speed + "m/hr";

},

};
```

I have tried a couple different ways to rectify this problem, the first is in my code now and is throwing the error in the title of this question. The second is trying just:

```
document.querySelector("#weatherIcon").src = `https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`;
```

this way throws the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set src...Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? As always, any help is appreciated!

Side note: the community has been extremely helpful to my learning process, and for this I am grateful. I'm extremely motivated to learn and eventually become fullstack even though right now I suck lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177417/how-to-display-openweathermap-weather-icon read this

Comment: Anna_Romantsova, thank you!

Comment: What is the HTML for the element with id of `weatherIcon`, and at what point of parsing the page does the code run - i.e. in the head section, at the bottom of the document body, or after a page load or document ready event has fired?

Comment: trakor, the ID is actually Weather-Icon. It was a typo originally but I have corrected it. And I needed to run after the data is fetched. Thank you in advance for your help.